# How to get the latest release from Github API using JSON

Tags: json, github, github-api

I have tried to get the latest release from github. I think I may be reading the array wrong. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var JS = JSON.parse(this.responseText);     
  console.log(JS.tag_name)
  
  
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/repos/NAME/REPO/releases", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

With the response from the console:

```
undefined
```

I am new to JSON so I am a little confused on how to read an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/repos/NAME/REPO/releases` returns an array of releases, and you want to get the first one with `JS[0].tag_name`.

If you just need the latest release, use `/repos/NAME/REPO/releases/latest` and keep `JS.tag_name`.